# How to change this code from c to c++

Tags: c++, c

I have learned C a lot and but not c++ and was just wondering what this code would like in c++. thanks. this is not for an assignment just more out of curiousity because i will be learning c++ next semester.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<math.h>

void rotateCW(FILE * ifp, FILE * ofp);

void rotateCounterCW(FILE * ifp, FILE * ofp);

int main(int argc, char *argv)
{
    FILE *ifp, *ofp;

    int ifpFlag = 0;

    //loops until valid input file is put in
    while(ifpFlag == 0)
    {
        char fnamer[100]="";
        printf("\nWhats the input file name?\n");
        scanf("%s", &fnamer);

        ifp = fopen(fnamer, "r");

        if (ifp == NULL)
        {
            fprintf(stderr, "Can't open input file in.list!\n");
        }
        else
        {
            ifpFlag = 1;
        }

    }

    char outname[100]="";
    printf("\nWhats the output file name?\n");
    scanf("%s", &outname);

    ofp = fopen(outname, "w");

    if (ofp == NULL)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Can't open output file %s!\n",
                outname);
        exit(1);
    }

    int flag = 0;

    //loops until valid input or quit
    while(flag == 0)
    {
        //print menu
        int input;
        printf("\nChoose an option:\n1)Rotate Clockwise 90 degrees\n2)Rotate Counter-Clockwise 90 degrees\n3)Quit\n");
        scanf("%d", &input);
        switch (input)
        {
            case 1:
                rotateCW(ifp,ofp);
                flag = 1;
                break;
            case 2:
                rotateCounterCW(ifp,ofp);
                flag = 1;
                break;
            case 3: //quit
                printf("\nProgram Terminated\n");
                flag = 1;
                break;
            default: //valid input was not put in
                printf("Invalid input.\n");
                break;
        }
    }

    fclose(ifp);
    fclose(ofp);

    return 0;

}

void rotateCounterCW(FILE * ifp, FILE * ofp)
{
    int length, width;
    fscanf(ifp, "%d", &width);
    fscanf(ifp, "%d", &length);
    int array[length][width];
    int CCWarray[length * width];
    int i, j, k;

    for (i = 0; i < length; i++)
    {
        for (j = 0; j < width; j++)
        {
            fscanf(ifp, "%d", &array[i][j]);
        }
    }

    k = 0;
    for (j = width - 1; j >= 0; --j)
    {
        for (i = 0; i < length; i++)
        {
            CCWarray[k++] = array[i][j];
        }
    }
    fprintf(ofp, "P2\n");
    fprintf(ofp, "# Comments here.\n");
    fprintf(ofp, "%d %d\n", length, width);
    fprintf(ofp, "255\n");

    //writing the output file
    for (i = 0; i < (length * width); i++)
    {
        fprintf(ofp, "%d ", CCWarray[i]);
    }
    fprintf(ofp, "\n");
    printf("\nThe pgm was rotated CCW by 90 degrees\n");
}

void rotateCW(FILE * ifp, FILE * ofp)
{
    int length, width;
    fscanf(ifp, "%d", &width);
    fscanf(ifp, "%d", &length);
    int array[length][width];
    int CWarray[length * width];
    int i, j, k;

    for (i = 0; i < length; i++)
    {
        for (j = 0; j < width; j++)
        {
            fscanf(ifp, "%d", &array[i][j]);
        }
    }

    k = 0;
    for (j = 0; j < width; j++)
    {
        for (i = length - 1; i >= 0; --i)
        {
            CWarray[k++] = array[i][j];
        }
    }
    fprintf(ofp, "P2\n");
    fprintf(ofp, "# Comments here.\n");
    fprintf(ofp, "%d %d\n", length, width);
    fprintf(ofp, "255\n");

    //writing the output file
    for (i = 0; i < (length * width); i++)
    {
        fprintf(ofp, "%d ", CWarray[i]);
    }
    fprintf(ofp, "\n");
    printf("\nThe pgm was rotated CW by 90 degrees\n");
}
```

Comment: You could likely compile directly with a C++ compiler and there would be no changes to make. You're gonna have to be more specific in how you want to make this code "C++"-esque.

Comment: `int array[length][width];` I think C++ does not have VLAs

Comment: Do you really want us to read through all this code? This question looks too broad to me. Can you narrow it down, please?

Comment: @JanDvorak I agree. I didn't even read the code.

Comment: Start by fixing your `main` declaration. `argv` is of type `char **`, not `char*`. As-is it isn't standard compliant.

Comment: .. so -- it's not even correct C to begin with!

Answer (score 2):

You've got some variable-length arrays, which are not allowed in C++.  Replace those with `std::vector`.

For example

```
int CCWarray[length * width];
```

becomes

```
std::vector<int> CCWarray;
CCWarray.resize(length * width);
```

The rest of the code (except the wrong type on `argv` which WhozCraig noted in a comment) is valid C++ already.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know C++, but, for starters ...

1. the includes would change
2. you'd use `cout` and `cin` and `<<` and `>>`
3. no more `char[]`, replaced with `std::string`

Comment: That's 3 ways to add bugs into working code.  When the behavior needs to change, then it's time to move to a more C++ style.  But style is a poor reason to throw away working code.

Comment: Although, the question did mention a desire to learn C++.  I guess that's a good reason.

Comment: Not just cout and cin , he also needs to use fstream in place of FILE.

Comment: @BenVoigt I totally agree with you, but C-code is sometimes written very poorly. I've enountered too many legacy codebases which just beg for a random crash at any given moment. Introducing C++-features will probably cause such a program to crash much more often at first, and in certain situations this is highly inappropriate, but it can pay off in the long run (_Crash often, crash early_). It all depends on your situation I guess.

Answer (score 0):

Most well formed C code is also C++ code. If you compile it with a C++ compiler it already *is* C++ (even if it is also C).  Some C language features added in C99 are not included in C++ - such as variable length arrays (as Ben Voigt has already pointed out), but many C++ compilers will support them by extension.

That said, some features of C are deprecated in C++ or have better alternatives in C++.  You can trivially C++'ize this code by using C++ style library headers, the std:: namespace, iostreams, the std::string class and STL containers, but that in itself conveys a useful but small advantage, and may leave you wondering why C++ is any better.

What C++ is good at is supporting object oriented programming, and to benefit from that requires a redesign of your code rather than a straight "conversion".  In other words - if you want to get to OOP don't start at procedural, start from the design.

Comment: But don't make the mistake of thinking C++ is object-oriented, since it is really multi-paradigm.  It supports OO code well, and generic code well, and functional code much better than C, and metaprogramming, and...

Comment: @BenVoigt That's what I said.  Perhaps not explicitly, but "well formed C is also C++" and "supporting object oriented programming" kind of suggests that,

Comment: Yes, that comment is to clarify, not correct.  I've seen people who think that C++ programming means OO, because they come from an OO-focused language like Java.  But C++ supports many styles.